# TSQL - How to format result of a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query:

```
select SentDate, SentTime, SeenDate, SeenTime
from Sents
```

The result is something like this:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
SentDate      SentTime      SeenDate         SeenTime
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
1394/01/09    10:44         1394/01/22         13:27     
1394/01/15    7:15          1394/01/22         14:41     
1394/01/15    7:21          1394/01/22         13:18     
1394/01/15    7:31          1394/01/22         14:47     
1394/01/15    8:28          1394/01/22         13:00     
1394/01/15    11:20         1394/01/22         13:41     
1394/01/16    9:9           1394/01/22         12:56     
1394/01/17    07:48         1394/01/22         12:58     
1394/01/17    07:49         1394/01/22         13:28     
1394/01/18    12:53         1394/01/22         14:43     
1394/01/19    10:33         1394/01/22         14:42     
1394/01/19    11:49         1394/01/22         10:59     
1394/01/20    08:00         1394/01/22         12:54     
1394/01/20    9:43          1394/01/22         10:52     
1394/01/20    9:51          1394/01/22         10:51     
1394/01/22    6:47          1394/01/22         10:50     
1394/01/22    6:50          1394/01/22         10:49     
1394/01/22    8:31          1394/01/22         10:39     
1394/01/22    9:12          1394/01/22         10:38
1394/01/22    9:12 PM       1394/01/22         10:38 PM
1394/01/23    09:10 PM      1394/01/22         10:9 AM
```

As you can see the Dates (SentDate, SeenDate) are OK in terms of formatting I mean their patterns are `^(\d{4})[-/](\d\d)[-/](\d\d(?:\d\d)?)`. The problem is SentTime and SeenTime, I want to formate them this way: `(\d{2}):(\d{2})`. 
First of all I have tried to get the first 5 characters this way:

```
select SentDate,LTRim(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(SentTime,1,5))), SeenDate, LTRim(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(SeenTime,1,5)))
from erja
```

But I have no idea for formatting values like `7:15` or `07:5` or `7:7`
Any idea?

**PS**: In the result I also have these type of values for the time:

```
11:45 ق
11:45 ب
```

Comment: What is the `Type` of your fields? Also i would suggest you to mention the version of your SQL server.

Comment: @Rohit their types are `char(10)` and the version of SQL Server is 2012

Comment: since your fields are `char` and not `Date`, `Time`, or `DateTime` and does not follow any format, you will have to use a lot `CASE`-`WHEN`-`THEN`.

Comment: Further... is 9:12 = 9:12 am or 9:12 pm? Your data is ambiguous.

Comment: @SirwanAfifi Sorry I don't know whats the meaning of ق and ب, which is AM, PM?

Comment: @Eric `ب` is PM in Persian and `ق` is AM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert it to datetime then convert back to char

```
SELECT 
    Value, REPLACE(REPLACE(Value, N'ق', 'AM'), N'ب', 'PM') AS ReplacedValue,
    CONVERT(varchar(5), 
    CONVERT(datetime, 
        REPLACE(REPLACE(Value, N'ق', 'AM'), N'ب', 'PM')
    )
    , 108) AS FormatTime 
FROM    
    (values
        ('10:9 AM'),
        ('09:10 PM '), 
        ('9:12 PM'), 
        ('9:12'), 
        ('07:5'), 
        ('7:7'),
        (N'11:45 ق'),
        (N'11:45 ب')
    ) data(Value)
```

**Result**

```
Value     ReplacedValue FormatTime
--------- ------------- ----------
10:9 AM   10:9 AM       10:09
09:10 PM  09:10 PM      21:10
9:12 PM   9:12 PM       21:12
9:12      9:12          09:12
07:5      07:5          07:05
7:7       7:7           07:07
11:45 ق   11:45 AM      11:45
11:45 ب   11:45 PM      23:45
```

Comment: but since there is **AM** and **PM** appended in the sample data, I think you cant be sure of what is *9:12*.

Comment: @Rohit That's true, let see what OP adds

Comment: Thanks, But What about this type of value:`07:5 ق` ?

Comment: `CONVERT()` never ceases to amaze me... :)

Comment: @SirwanAfifi See edit. I am not sure if SQL server can handle other language in a better way than `REPLACE()`.